# Is there any way to add images to the Media Library through a path on the server?

Tags: media-library

I have 3 folders with images that I want to add to my media library. I do not want to have them uploaded under the default path (i.e. uploads/year/month). I can upload them anywhere in the theme folder.

Is there any plugin/method to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Add From Server](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/) plugin.