# What if I have a large file on the server that I want the wp library to have?

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

I have one server that has wordpress in the root directory. However before I installed wordpress, I also have (root)/videos. I'm sure I can move this folder anywhere, however I want to move it to a place so wordpress can add it to its media library. This way, I can easily select it. I don't want (and I can't) re-upload these large video files through the wordpress upload.

Thank you

Comment: Check out: http://cyberinnovation.com/plugins/adding-large-files-to-wordpress-media-library-via-ftp-or-file-upload/

Comment: Ryan! You should have posted this as a comment! This is the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did flag this question as a duplicate of this one: [Is there any way to add images to the Media Library through a path on the server?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/46129/12615).
Which points to the plugin [Add to Server](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/) as the article linked by @RyanB in the comments...

But, wondering on the issue, a creative solution is uploading a bunch of dummy files with the same names of the big ones and replace them with the real ones inside the `/uploads/` folder. This would only work with audio and video files as they don't generate thumbnails nor metadata.